# SQL Server table running out of int values on primary key

Tags: sql-server

I have a VERY big table (let's say the table name is `ASTable`) thats need to be handled in 2 ways:

- The primary key (`ASTableID`) is running out of int values and needs to be changed to `bigint`
- The (`ASTable`) then need to be moved to an archive server

I would like to share my plan of action for discussion please.

High level plan of action:

1. Stop the application using the database
2. Rename the table (`ASTable`) with `sp_rename` to `ASTable_Old`
3. Create a new table with name that will be the production table: `ASTable` with `ASTableID bigint`
4. Create `ASTable` foreign keys with name ending with `_New`
5. Create `ASTable` indexes with name ending with `_New`
6. Alter all stored procedures to change references to `ASTableID` from int to bigint
7. Start application
8. Move `ASTable_Old` to archive server

Some stats regarding the `ASTable`:

- Rowcount: 1 791 184 696 - 1.7 billion rows
- Data Space Used (KB): 210 547 352 - that is 210 GB
- Index Space Used (KB): 420 563 976 - that is 420 GB

I am running out of time to handle this issue and any comments would be very welcome.

Comment: Seems to be missing any data migration step from old to new. Do you not need the old data in the new table? Also are ids generated by `IDENTITY`? I don't see any step to start that seeding at a higher value than current rows

Comment: See [here](https://littlekendra.com/2016/08/04/altering-an-int-column-to-a-bigint-dear-sql-dba-episode-11/). But if you're stopping the application can't you just do it online?

Comment: For future reference - most people typically start identity columns at 1 and increase. That leaves HALF of the domain of the datatype unusable. Just reseed and start at the opposite (negative) end - negative identity values are not scary. I think I should add that many coders make assumptions about identity values being greater than zero - so this approach depends on how well the code is written.

Comment: Thanks for comment, nearly forgot to set identity number. Yep, using IDENTITY and will reseed to max ID + 1 million to make provision for records coming in by accident. Currently the records is coming into the main table at around 1.75 million per day.

Comment: Interesting thought about negative identity! Never thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of schemas. This way your naming of columns and keys separate easily.

The power lies in the CREATE SCHEMA command. Once the archive (schema or shorter "arch") is created the option is to move the table with ALTER SCHEMA. I have never tested this approach on such a big table. I am not sure if this recreates the table or just updates the schema_id in the system tables.

Dummy code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
  testcolumn  int   NOT NULL
)
;

INSERT INTO dbo.Test
VALUES (100000)
;

ALTER SCHEMA conf
TRANSFER dbo.Test
;
```

(*) In my database the schema "conf" already exists.

Using schemas allows to re-use all existing columns. Therefore apart from the change of ID creation from int to bigint all existing code and references keeps working.

On another note for the archive: Drop all your foreign key referencing on the archive table once moved to the new schema.

Additionally there is the option to move the table in whole to a read only file group to prevent it from being manipulated later. However this induces a data transfer between the file groups so best done all the work is finished and downtime can be scheduled.

Comment: One word of caution with switch schemas - any permissions that exist on the object before the move are dropped. And to address your other question, `alter schema` is indeed a metadata operation.